# Need Client Side Validation for TextBox if '<' and '>' are used in textbox ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, textbox, client-side-validation

Could you please Suggest a client Side Validation for the TextBox in ASP.NET. Needs validation and should not allow user to use '<>'. When text is entered between '<' and '>', it should show validation

Comment: i think you need to validate any html tag entered, then its the case, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790681/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags

Comment: Here, I need to stop the user to enter '<>'. If user enters this, then they should get a validation message @ShaminderSAujla

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `CustomValidator`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="customvalidator1"   ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
EnableClientScript="true" ErrorMessage="Cannot accept- < or >" ClientValidationFunction="jsvalidate" />
```

below script should be placed in aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function jsvalidate(sender, args) {
            debugger;
            var val = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value;
            if ((val.indexOf('<') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('>') !== -1)) {
                alert("Error");
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
            else
             {
              args.IsValid = true;
              }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: that was really helpful. It is working fine :)

It will be helpful if you update the script in such a way that : 
if any text is there in between '<' and '>' is present, then only is should show validation. Otherwise no validation required
@balaji

Comment: can;t get you, please elaborate with an Update